# how to remove style from text

Tags: php, styles

I have to display a content from database.The content is added using an editor.
I used the code below to display it

```
 <?php echo $record['content'];?>
```

It displays like below

```
description
<style type="text/css">
body { background-color: #fff; padding: 0 20px; color:#000; font: 13px/18px Arial, sans-serif; }
a { color: #360; }
h3 { padding-top: 20px; }
ol { margin:5px 0 15px 16px; padding:0; list-style-type:square; }
#player1_wrapper{
description border:2px solid #B5B5B5;
}
</style>
```

style also displays with the content.How can I remove this?I only need text content that is the description only.I have to remove that style content.
I tried `html_entity_decode` but no effect

Comment: you mean description ? only ??

Comment: May be the previous div is not getting completed properly. Can you give a little bit of the previous code?

Comment: Or maybe you only want the text between the <style> tags?

Comment: I only need the description.not need that style tags

Comment: $record['content']; contains syle tags ?

Comment: yes..it is added using editor

Comment: Probably best to not use a HTML editor for input in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo(preg_replace('/<style[^>]*>(([^<]|[<[^\/]|<\/[^s]|<\/s[^t])*)<\/style>/i','',$record['content']));
```

I'm on mobile phone, so  code is untested... but that's the idea...

**EDIT** Now tested the code, there was a missing ')' and added removal of newlines/returns after  tag:

```
<?php


echo(preg_replace('/[\n\r ]*<style[^>]*>(([^<]|[<[^\/]|<\/[^s]|<\/s[^t])*)<\/style>[\n\r ]*/i','',$record['content']));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo  preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', ' ', $record['content']));
```

Comment: description<style type="text/css">  body { background-color: #fff; padding: 0 20px; color:#000; font: 13px/18px Arial, sans-serif; } a { color: #360; } h3 { padding-top: 20px; } ol { margin:5px 0 15px 16px; padding:0; list-style-type:square; } #player1_wrapper{ description border:2px solid #B5B5B5; } </style> body { background: #FFF; }

Comment: do you want to hide the full <style type="text/css"> body { background-color: #fff; padding: 0 20px; color:#000; font: 13px/18px Arial, sans-serif; } a { color: #360; } h3 { padding-top: 20px; } ol { margin:5px 0 15px 16px; padding:0; list-style-type:square; } #player1_wrapper{ description border:2px solid #B5B5B5; } </style> body { background: #FFF; }  ? or just <style> </style> tags ?

Comment: i have to hide the full <style type="text/css">

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## editted:

```
$string1=$record['content'];
$pos=strpos($string1,"<");
$string2=substr($string1,0,$pos);
```

I have not tried it. But it should work. This is in case you dont want the style tags.

Comment: It takes the count of text in style also..$length is 996

Comment: Are the style tags saved in the database?